# Phonegap and webworks

Tags: html, cordova, blackberry-webworks

I have downloaded the webworks sdk 2.3.0.9 because the latest one will not compile my phonegap app on my computer.

What do i need to include in my html file to get access to the webworks methods like the push messaging.

I have got my app up but need to include push notifications for blackberry

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to get the notifications sort of working however I cannot get them to come through when I have closed the application. I am aware that this is a new question so I will post it on a new thread.

No link to the webworks.js file is required. I was compiling it incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the feature tag to your config.xml file

```
<feature id="blackberry.push" />
```

As for using that feature you can find detailed instructions here https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/api/blackberry.push.html

Comment: <feature id="blackberry.media.camera" />
  <feature id="blackberry.ui.dialog" />
  <feature id="blackberry.push" />
  <feature id="blackberry.media.microphone" required="true" version="1.0.0.0"/>

Comment: Its there still the blackberry.push is undefined

Comment: Try comparing your code to the push example on Github? https://github.com/blackberry/BB10-WebWorks-Samples/tree/master/pushCapture

Comment: It should be included in the SDK you downloaded as mentioned here https://github.com/blackberry/BB10-WebWorks-Samples/issues/7

Comment: I tried to include the file however I still have no luck

 try {
      var ops = {port : port, appId : appId, serverUrl : serverUrl, wakeUpPage : 'not.html', maxQueueCap : max};
      alert(blackberry);
   blackberry.push.openBISPushListener(ops, onData, onRegister, onSimChange);
   alert('End Push');
    }
    catch (err) {
      alert(err);
    }

Comment: When i look at the webworks js file their is no openBISPushListener method

Comment: Can you find that method within the latest version of the SDK?

Comment: I will be looking into compiling with the new skd later this year. You can follow the project on my blog http://programmersgabble.blogspot.com/